# Long multiplication in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, multiplication

How would you implement long multiplication on lists in Haskell. The idea being that if you have two numbers, let's say 112 and 13. These numbers can be represented as lists [1,1,2] and [1,3] and you want to multiply them together to get a list [1,4,5,6]. I want to do this recursively as I want it to work on any size list. My "functionWhichSumsLists" is a function I will define later which will add two lists element-wise.

```
longMulti l1 [] = p1
longMulti [] l2 = q1
longMulti (li:l1) (lii:l2) = functionWhichSumsLists [li*lii] (0:(longMulti l1 l2))
```

Comment: If you want to cheat by converting back and forth between `Integer`: `longMulti x y = longMulti x y = map (read . (:[])) . show $ read (concatMap show x) * read (concatMap show y)` (it will need a type signature to work correctly because of `read`).  Otherwise you will have to think about how multiplication works, which is what I think you are actually after.  Step 1: before coding, explain how to multiply two numbers in gruesome detail.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than converting back and forth to `String` with `show`, you can use modular arithmetic.

```
toDigits :: Integral a => a -> [a]
toDigits = go [] where
  go acc 0 = acc
  go acc x = let (xs, x') = x `divMod` 10
             in go (x':acc) xs
```

Then `fromDigits` can be implemented with a `foldl`.

```
import Data.List (foldl')

fromDigits :: Integral a => [a] -> a
fromDigits = foldl' (\acc x -> acc * 10 + x) 0
```

or indeed with `zipWith (*)`

```
-- note: this is significantly slower than above because of the necessary
--       calls to reverse.
fromDigits = sum . reverse . (zipWith (*) [10^i | i <- [0..]]) . reverse
```

---

What's left is the multiplication itself. Do be careful though, because the naive approach doesn't work here.

```
terms = [112, 13]
[xs, ys] = map toDigits terms
wrongAnswer = fromDigits $ zipWith (*) xs ys
-- 13
```

`zipWith (*) [1, 1, 2] [1, 3]`, as above, becomes `[1*1, 1*3]` which is obviously wrong when you sit down and imagine it. Well then, we have to cross multiply and sum, right?

```
alsoWrong = fromDigits $ answerDigits where
  answerDigits = zipWith (+) [map (*y) xs | y <- ys]
-- 448
```

This expands out to

```
zipWith (+) [map (*1) [1, 1, 2], map (*3) [1, 1, 2]]
= zipWith (+) [[1, 1, 2], [3, 3, 6]]
= [(1+3), (1+3), (2+6)]
= [4, 4, 8] -- fromDigits yields 448
```

This is equivalent to doing by hand:

```
    112
   x 13
   ----
    336
    112  <--- note this should be slid to the left
   ----
    448
```

So instead we can apply a similar technique to the folding `fromDigits` to each term.

```
sum $ map fromDigits $ zipWith (\p xs -> map (*p) xs) tens eachProduct where
  tens        = [10^i | i <- [len-1, len-2..0]]
  eachProduct = [map (*y) xs | y <- ys]
  len         = length eachProduct
```

ending up with:

```
longMultiplication :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
longMultiplication x y = sum . map fromDigits . zipWith mapper tens $ eachProduct where
    xs          = toDigits x
    ys          = toDigits y
    mapper      = (\p xs -> map (*p) xs)
    tens        = [10^i | i <- [len-1, len-2..0]]
    len         = length eachProduct
    eachProduct = [map (*y') xs | y' <- ys]
```